# React-navigation: with TabNavigator is it possible to listen to screens position during swipe?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I got a [TabNavigator](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/tab) set up and i'd like to retrieve screens postions during the swipe.

```
const MainScreenNavigator = TabNavigator({
  ProfileStack: { screen: ProfileStack },
  Home: { screen: Home },
  HistoryStack: { screen: HistoryStack }
}, {
  swipeEnabled: true
});
```

How to do so? is it possible without using [Transitioner](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/views/transitioner)?

Comment: I am also looking for a solution to this, were you able to figure out?